# Curve fitting with 5 parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, fuzzy-logic

I am working on a curve fitting problem with the input function of the form

```
n=((xi-xa)-a*cos(theta))^2+(h-a*sin(theta))^2;
d=((xi-xa)+a*cos(theta))^2+(h+a*sin(theta))^2;
v=k*log(n/d) : Input function
```

Here xa,a,theta,h and k are parameters and we are required to compute v(xi)

The plot looks like this
[image]

Here blue dots represent observed value and red line is the theoretical curve obtained from the input function.

This fitting process was done by manually varying the parameters and matching the curves using hit and trial.
Could this be accomplished using any optimization technique in Matlab. if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use lsqcurvefit (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html), e.g.

```
function F = myfun(x,xdata)
   %your parameters xa,a,theta,h,k
   %map to parameter vector x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5)

   n = ((xdata-x(1))-x(2)*cos(x(3)))^2+(x(4)-x(2)*sin(x(3)))^2;
   d = ((xdata-x(1))+acos(x(3)))^2+(x(4)+asin(x(3)))^2;
   F =  x(5)*log(n/d);
end
```

and a call to solver

```
x0 = [1;1;1;1;1]; % your guess for starting values of the x vector of parameters
x = lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata);
```